# In Middleman how do I generate day, month, and year blog archive links?

Tags: middleman

I'm trying to generate year and month archive links.

Right now I can set one of the three. 
When I set two or more and look at the Sitemap I get the error:

```
NoMethodError at /__middleman/sitemap/
undefined method `add_path' for #<Middleman::MetaPages::SitemapResource:0x007fedd61597a0>`
```

Here is my blog from config.rb

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.name = "blog"
  blog.permalink = "/{title}/"
  blog.taglink = "blog/:tag.html"
  blog.year_link = "blog/{year}/"
  blog.month_link = "blog/{year}/{month}/"
  blog.day_link = "blog/{year}/{month}/{day}/"
  blog.sources = "blog/{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html"
  #blog.year_template = "blog/calendar.html"
  blog.month_template = "blog/calendar.html"
  #blog.day_template = "blog/calendar.html"


  blog.layout = "blog-layout"

  blog.tag_template = "blog/tag.html"

  #blog.calendar_template = "blog/calendar.html"

  # This will add a prefix to all links, template references and source paths
  # blog.prefix = "blog"

  # Matcher for blog source files
  # blog.sources = "{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html"
  # blog.summary_separator = /(READMORE)/
  # blog.summary_length = 250
  # blog.default_extension = ".markdown"

  # Enable pagination
  # blog.paginate = true
  # blog.per_page = 10
  # blog.page_link = "page/{num}"
end
```